# How to display a block only for a certain category page

Tags: categories

How can I display a block that i placed in a widget area only if a certain category page comes up? For example in the sidebar of my theme i have certain blocks which display on all category pages. but one of them, i want to be visible only if a certain category page is clicked. what must i do?

Comment: Would it not be easier to build a block as a container/wrapper so that you can insert any block you want inside and they only show on that category page? Also do you mean category archive or is this a page with a page template/page builder that has a query for a category? Can you add some context for what you're hoping to achieve that requires this? E.g. is it to hide/show a subscription prompt for example? Use the `Edit` link to add to your question, any context and information will help get better answers and avoid unnecessary follow-up questions

Comment: I thought my question was clear and I never meant all those possibilities you wrote. it is simply what you see on screen when you click one of the categories. in the simplest way everyone understands from "category" in wordpress. So if I click on that specific category, I want that content to appear in the sidebar. otherwise, if home page or any other page whatsoever, (other category, post, regular page....), i want that content in the sidebar to disappear.

Comment: Are you using a custom theme or child theme? It wouldn't be too difficult to create a different sidebar for this one category and only add the widget there. If memory serves, WP outputs widget wrappers before the widgets themselves, so even if you coded something like "if this is the special category, output this html, but if not, output nothing" you'd end up with an empty `<li>`.

Comment: i m using default wordpress theme that everyone knows, which is 2016. look at the side bar. assume you clicked a category. i want something on side bar to appear only when that category page is active. any other page, such as home page, a post page, other catgeory page .... i want that content to disappear from sidebar.

Comment: for example look at the site i am working on. robothaber.com. look at the sidebar there. for example you see the links above the animated robotr that kicks a football? i want those links to appear onlyh when the category "etkinlikler" is clicked and that page comes up. not when home page or any other category or post page is active... only when the category "etkinlikler" is active... note: this is the main 2016 theme. not child theme.